# Programming Optical 3D-sensors after difficult measurement in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 3d

I obtained three dimensional data from my optical system in Visual C++.And I want to show this profiler on windows form application.Is there any special library you could advise to me?And How can I customize this library in Visual C++.

Could you help me please?

Yours Sincerely....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're refering to a way to display that 3D data:

You can use [QT library](http://qt.nokia.com/). It has both UI support and OpenGL support, so you can display 3D data. It is cross platform, and there is a plug-in for Visual Studio that can ease your development under Windows.